# Deleting Android ListView in runtime

Tags: android

Hi I have ListView and I want to delete all the element in runtime.How can I do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call `adapter.clear()` followed by `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` when you want to delete the elements.

Answer (score 1):

ListView is fed from an adapter. Have an adapter that can return 0 items. Or reset an adapter to an array adapter over a zero-length array.

Comment: I can confirm that setting the adapter data source to 0 and then calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() works.